# EditText width of hidden text

Tags: java, android

I have a custom `EditText` class. In this `EditText`, I need to find out a width of input. Depending by `inputType` of `EditText`, the text has different width values.

For example:

```
final String text = "azazaz";
setText(text);
```

1. inputType is password, so user see that : ****** (40px for e.g)
2. no inputType, so user see that : azazaz (60px for e.g.)

But the following code will set the same value of `textWidth` in both options (width of text without `inputType`)

```
final Paint p = new Paint();
p.setTextSize(getTextSize());
final float textWidth = p.measureText(text);
```

**QUESTION** : How can I find a real width value of text with password inputType?

Answer (score 2):

You can try to calculate the width of the string composed from the same amount of the passcode characters:

```
public static float calculateTextWidth(TextView textView, String text) {
    final Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setTextSize(textView.getTextSize());

    String output = text;
    TransformationMethod method = textView.getTransformationMethod();
    if (method != null) {
        output = (String) method.getTransformation(text, textView);
    }
    return p.measureText(output);
}
```

Comment: it may be good solution, but  text is hidden not by "\*" symbols. Text is hidden by non-symbolyc dots. I use "\*" as sign of this dots.

Comment: @P.Ilyin I've edited my answer to detect passcode symbol dynamically

Comment: You could do `password =  method.getTransformation(text, textView);` and eliminate the loop and `StringBuilder`